# Sort function with undefined value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting, filtering

I have an array of object like below:

```
 var stores = [
      {
        "name": "store3",
        "ditance": 8
      },
      {
        "name": "Store5",
        "distance": 7,
        "web": {
          "validateAttributes": {
            "isSelectedDispostionSupported": true,
            "isFutureOrderPossible": false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Store1",
        "distance": 12,
        "web": {
          "validateAttributes": {
            "isSelectedDispostionSupported": true,
            "isOpen": true
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "store2",
        "distance": 13,
        "web": {
          "validateAttributes": {
            "isSelectedDispostionSupported": true,
            "isOpen": true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Expected  Result to be sort based on isopen and distance

```
[
  {
    "name": "Store1",
    "distance": 12,
    "web": {
      "validateAttributes": {
        "isSelectedDispostionSupported": true,
        "isOpen": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "store2",
    "distance": 13,
    "web": {
      "validateAttributes": {
        "isSelectedDispostionSupported": true,
        "isOpen": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Store5",
    "distance": 7,
    "web": {
      "validateAttributes": {
        "isSelectedDispostionSupported": true,
        "isFutureOrderPossible": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "store3",
    "ditance": 8
  }
]
```

Need to sort an array based on isOpen and distance  .The challenge is some object have web property and some object don't have. Even if web available sometimes isOpen won't their. I have tried the below approch it's not working

```
const sorter = (a, b) => {
                if (a.web) {
                  if (a.web.validateAttributes) {
                    if (a.web.validateAttributes.isOpen) {
                      return 1;
                    } else if (b.web.validateAttributes.isOpen) {
                      return -1;
                    } else {
                      return 1;
                    };
                  } else {
                    return 1;
                  }
                 
                } else {
                  return 1;
                }
              };
  stores.sort(sorter);
```

Comment: what should be the expected result? Please add it in question itself...

Comment: @decpk Provided

Comment: Do you really have a `ditance` property on only one of your entries?

Comment: @Phil distance also their. Need to sort based on isOpen first and distance

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
const stores = [{"name":"store3","ditance":8},{"name":"Store5","distance":7,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isFutureOrderPossible":false}}},{"name":"Store1","distance":12,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isOpen":true}}},{"name":"store2","distance":13,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isOpen":true}}}]

   const sorter = (a,b)=> {
      if(!b.web) {
          return -1;
      }
      else if(!b.web.validateAttributes) {
        return -1;
      }
      else if(!b.web.validateAttributes.isOpen) {
        return -1;
      }
      return (a.distance - b.distance)
   }
   console.log(stores.sort(sorter))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
const stores = [{"name":"store3","ditance":8},{"name":"Store5","distance":7,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isFutureOrderPossible":false}}},{"name":"Store1","distance":12,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isOpen":true}}},{"name":"store2","distance":13,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isOpen":true}}}]

const sorted = stores.slice();

sorted.sort((a, b) => {
    if (!a.web || !b.web) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (!a.web.validateAttributes || !b.web.validateAttributes) {
        return -1;
    }
    const x = a.web.validateAttributes.isOpen || false;
    const y = b.web.validateAttributes.isOpen || false;

    return (x === y) ? a.distance - b.distance : -1;
})
console.log(sorted)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 problems.

1. typo at the first item "ditance": 8
2. Your sorting function.
   Here is my logic. Firstly, check both are Opening or Closing, then compare distance.
   Else just simple compare the state open/close

```js
var stores = [{"name":"store3","distance":8},{"name":"Store5","distance":7,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isFutureOrderPossible":false}}},{"name":"Store1","distance":12,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isOpen":true}}},{"name":"store2","distance":13,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isOpen":true}}}];
    
stores.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.web?.validateAttributes?.isOpen && b.web?.validateAttributes?.isOpen || !a.web?.validateAttributes?.isOpen && !b.web?.validateAttributes?.isOpen) {
    return a.distance - b.distance;
  }
  if (a.web?.validateAttributes?.isOpen) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 1;
})

console.log(stores);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to turn the `isOpen` properties into a -1 if *truthy* or 1 if *falsy* to establish their position.

If those properties are equal, then fallback to a distance comparison.

```js
// fixed "ditance" to "distance" in "store3"
const stores = [{"name":"store3","distance":8},{"name":"Store5","distance":7,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isFutureOrderPossible":false}}},{"name":"Store1","distance":12,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isOpen":true}}},{"name":"store2","distance":13,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isOpen":true}}}]

const sorted = [...stores].sort((a, b) => 
  (a.web?.validateAttributes?.isOpen ? -1 : 1) -
  (b.web?.validateAttributes?.isOpen ? -1 : 1) ||
  (a.distance - b.distance))
  
console.log(sorted)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

After fixing some typos here is another alternative.

If not set, default each `isOpen` to `false` and store.
If they are the same, sort on `distance`, otherwise sort on the `isOpen`.

This uses a combination of the [Optional Chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [Nullish Coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

The Optional Chaining operator will return `null` if any property along the chain does not exist. So in the case of `.web` or `.isOpen` not existing a `null` is produced.

That is followed by the Nullish Caolescing operator so that if a `null` is produced as above, the default value is `false` so that the sort order is based upon that value (`true` will be placed before `false`.

```js
let stores = [{"name":"Store1","distance":13,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isOpen":true}}},{"name":"store2","distance":12,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isOpen":true}}},{"name":"Store5","distance":8,"web":{"validateAttributes":{"isSelectedDispostionSupported":true,"isFutureOrderPossible":false}}},{"name":"store3","distance":7}];

function comparator(a,b) {
  let aResult = a?.web?.validateAttributes?.isOpen ?? false;
  let bResult = b?.web?.validateAttributes?.isOpen ?? false;
  return (aResult === bResult)? a.distance - b.distance : bResult - aResult;
}
console.log(stores.sort(comparator));
```